# Apache Camel SFTP .filepart

Tags: apache-camel

I am reading files from one Linux box and uploading to another box using Apache Camel SFTP. it is working fine for up to 12MB files. If I upload morethan 12 MB file, I can see 2 files in desitnation box.

1. original file ( 1.pdf)
2. 1.pdf.filepart

How to remove the second .filepart file from desitnation box after completing upload using Camel SFTP route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "include" option for the sftp endpoint. All the file based endpoints have same(some times similar) options which can be found in the below links.

[Camel File](http://camel.apache.org/file.html) and [Camel File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

For you problem you need to use the include option and mention the your filename with extention as below

```
<from uri="file:Subfolder?include=myfilename.txt">
```

or

```
<from uri="file:Subfolder?include=*.txt">
```

Now having solved the issue of reading multiple files. Now you might(happens on case to case basis especially for large files) face the issue of reading the large file before it is being fully copied. If this happens you need to use the option "readLock" or its related options based on the issue you may face ahead. Please go through the above mentioned links for more ideas.

Comment: I will read all files from source folder and upload the same file in desitnation folder. Functionality is working fine. but if source file size is > 12 MB, then desitnation folder have 2 file . 1 original and another one .filepart. My question here is how to avoid creating .filepart when i use Camel SFTP

Comment: As of what I know once the file is copied completely then the .filepart file will be deleted. Are you using in a situation to use readLock in the source endpoint? .

Comment: I would also assume the sftp library would delete the .filepart when its completely done. The .filepart is not something we do in Apache Camel source code.